# open source RTSP/RTP stack with C language

Tags: c

I look for an open source RTSP/RTP stack with C language because I want to connect from a micro-controller to media servers to play internet radio stations

Answer (score 1):

[live555](http://www.live555.com) is an open source project which contains RTSP/RTP stack, implemented in C++.
So you may need to encapsulates a C interface to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [webradio project](http://code.google.com/p/arm-webradio/) that runs on ARM Cortex-M3 platforms and includes RTSP Shoutcast/Icecast functionalty.  It looks like they wrote their own stack. I'm not sure how portable it might be. It looks like it's maybe at least minimally abstracted from the StellarisWare drivers they're using.  It's under the New BSD License as well.

Answer (score 0):

Given the question is about RTSP on microcontrollers (Cortex-M and similar), this obviously eliminates the most commonly used libraries for less constrained systems (gtreamer, vlc and friends).

For those landing here because of the RTSP, and more interested in the video streaming, the one that I found is https://github.com/geeksville/Micro-RTSP, which seems to tick most boxes: designed for MCUs, can be extended to support other cameras, and even support posix.

It does seems unmaintained at this time though.

Answer (score -1):

A number of open source clients for RTSP/RTP exist such as mplayer, xine, gstreamer, vlc, etc. -- all of them have client code for RTSP/RTP within them.